# IF (SUBQUERY) = SOMETHING SELECT A ELSE SELECT B MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

In Sql Server, I can do something like this:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN=VALUE) = 0
SELECT 1,2,3
ELSE SELECT A,B,C FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN=VALUE
```

I use that a lot, but now I have to work with MySql and I can't really get that to work :)

I guess the same applies to an upsert:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN=VALUE) = 0
INSERT INTO TABLE(COLUMN, OTHERCOLUMN) VALUES(VALUE, OTHERVALUE)
ELSE
UPDATE TABLE SET OTHERCOLUMN=OTHERVALUE WHERE COLUMN=VALUE
```

Ho do you do 'if subquery else' in MySql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT 1,2,3) s
WHERE
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN=VALUE) = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT
  A,B,C
FROM
  TABLE
WHERE
  COLUMN=VALUE
```

Comment: This one works fine for me. But I must say that the Sql Server if-else is a little more 'flexible'. If A, B, C are functions such as COUNT, AVG, MAX you get two results, but of course I can fix that with limit 1

Comment: @Jesper i think as well that the sql server is more flexible in this situation, this is just a "dirty" trick to make it work in mysql. You could fix that with limit 1 or you can use a subquery again like `SELECT * FROM (SELECT A,B,C ... WHERE ...) WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)...)>0` but id doesn't look as nice as in sql server...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that columns a, b, and c do not have `NULL` values, you can use this as well:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(t.a, 1) AS a,
    COALESCE(t.b, 2) AS b,
    COALESCE(t.c, 3) AS c
FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS dummy FROM dual) AS d
  LEFT JOIN
    TableX AS t 
      ON t.columnX = Value ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this...

```
select * from (
    select a, b, c
    from table t1
    where column = someValue
    union
    select 1, 2, 3) t2 limit 1
```

Comment: Quite nice, but you are missing a paranthese at 'select (1'

Comment: @Jesper not quite. paren was missing from first line, and didn't need one around the first select. Fixed. Thanks.